# Improper Integral of $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, polylogarithm

I was wondering how we would compute $\int\frac{x}{\sin(x)}dx$. I typed it into Wolfram Alpha and it came up with some crazy functions:
[image]

I am really curious as to how Wolfram Alpha came up with this expression. Also, I was wondering if the imaginary part of the expression is always $-2.5i$ because Wolfram Alpha gave this graph:

[image]

Sorry for the long post!

Comment: It seems like integration by parts should clear up the $x$ part so that you can focus on the trig part...

Comment: Since it's an indefinite integral, there is an arbitrary constant.  The constant that WA happened to choose makes the values on $(-\pi, \pi)$  complex.  You could just as well take the antiderivative to be $0$ at $x=0$, and then it would be real for all $x \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But the constant is real though, so wouldn't it have no effect the imaginary part of the expression?

Comment: First of all, there's not really "the" constant.  If you take one particular antiderivative as reference, every other antiderivative is that one plus a constant.  There's no reason to suppose that constant has to be real.

Answer (score 1):

WA noted that for $Im(z) > 0$ : $$\int_0^z\frac{ x}{\sin x}dx=
\int_0^z\frac{2i x}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}dx
 = \int_0^z  \frac{2i xe^{ix} }{e^{2ix}-1}dx = -2i  \int_0^z x \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{i (2k-1) x}dx \\ = -2i \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^z x  e^{i (2k-1) x}dx \\ =  -2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{e^{i (2k-1) z}}{ 2k-1}-\int_0^z  \frac{e^{i(2 k-1) x}}{2k-1}dx)=  -2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i (2k-1) z}}{ 2k-1}-  \frac{e^{i(2 k-1) x}}{2i(2k-1)^2}\\ =- \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{(-1)^ke^{i k z}}{ k}-  \frac{(-1)^k e^{ik x}}{2ik^2}+\frac{e^{i k z}}{ 2k-1}-  \frac{e^{i k x}}{2ik^2}
\\ = \log(1-e^{i z})-\log(1+e^{i z}) + \frac{1}{2i} Li_2(e^{i z})+\frac{1}{4i} Li_2(-e^{i z})$$
or something like that...

Where for $|z| \le 1$ : $Li_2(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^2}$

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!!! There is one small part I don't get though. Shouldn't the denominator in the third step be $e^{2ix}-1$ ?

Comment: @JoeTaylor yes of course, and there are many other typos, since the result is different from expected, but the idea is there

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry just one more question. How did you move from the third step to the fourth step. Did you simplify the fraction using a summation formula?